# Merging Options

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, attribute-options

Hi to everyone,

can I Merge Options from different Attributes?

I have 3 Attributes (Length, Width and Height) that allows Customer to Filter Products by Length and/or Width and/or Height.

In the Product Pages I would to Merge these 3 Attributes in one (Dimensions) that contains something like LxWxH. In this way it becomes more quick for the Customer.

Any Idea?

I have find one Store with this feature but I don't know if it really merging the Attributes or what.

Thanks.

Goodbye

Answer (score 1):

These attribute values are stored in the table catalog_eav_attribute, and if you aren't careful cleaning up the old attributes and values, your site will crash and you won't be able to recover without fixing these attribute mismatches in the database. Very risky work here. To move data from past orders, you'd need to write a MySQL query after creating the new attribute or do it manually--or don't worry about old orders.

I would just create the new attribute LxWxH and deactive the others. You'll need to keep these old attributes if you want to view orders from the past, so don't delete, just disable them.

Note that if you every have site migrate problems, this attribute mess will likely be one the issues.